# jQuery clipboard content + addition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, clipboard

I want to change (on copy event) content of clipboard to current content + some self text. Is there any way, how can I do that with jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

This might help: [Clipboard Content](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/clipboard)

Answer (score 1):

There are many jQuery "copy to clipboard" plugins just like [zClip](http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/). Take a look at them.